# Safe data from checkedlistbox checked unchecked?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have the checkedlistbox(**cbl1**) which is changing his items while user searching username in the textbox. The problem is that when function for display result of the searching from dynamic array on **cbl1**. The checking states "checked or unchecked" he throws OutOfRangeException'cause the size of items is changing. So I tried to use temporary checkedlistbox(**cbl2**) to save previous data of **cbl1** but it is not working.
Here is example:

```csharp
 private Task DisplayFound(HashSet<string> foundValues)
        {
            CheckedListBox temp = new CheckedListBox();
            temp.Sorted = true;
            temp.Items.Clear();

            CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection newItems = temp.Items;

            for (int i = 0; i < foundValues.Count; i++)
            {
               // here is problem
                if (checkedlistbox_users.GetItemChecked(i) == true)
                {
                    newItems.Add(foundValues.ElementAt(i));
                    temp.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                    continue;
                }
                newItems.Add(foundValues.ElementAt(i));
                temp.SetItemChecked(i, false);
            }

            checkedlistbox_users.Items.Clear();

            checkedlistbox_users.Items.AddRange(temp.Items);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        private async void searchUpdater_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textbox_username.TextLength > 0)
            {
                string text = textbox_username.Text.ToLower();

                if (CB_botsFilter.Checked)
                {
                    HashSet<string> foundBots = usernames.FindAll(x => x.StartsWith(text) && x.ToLower().Contains("bot")).ToHashSet();
                    await DisplayFound(foundBots);
                    return;
                }
                if (CB_peopleFilter.Checked)
                {
                    HashSet<string> foundPeople = usernames.FindAll(x => x.StartsWith(text) && !x.ToLower().Contains("bot")).ToHashSet();
                    await DisplayFound(foundPeople);
                    return;
                }

                HashSet<string> found = usernames.FindAll(x => x.ToLower().StartsWith(text)).ToHashSet();
                await DisplayFound(found);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do; however, it is easy to understand “why” you may be getting an index out of range error. The `for` loop assumes that `foundValues.Count` will ALWAYS be less than or equal to the number of items in the checked list box. If `foundValues.Count` is greater than the number of items in the checked list box, then the code … `checkedlistbox_users.GetItemChecked(i)` … is guaranteed to throw an out of bounds exception.

Comment: It appears you're using a Timer to update a Control. It's also not clear what stops or suspends the Timer. It's not clear at all why you're using a Timer here. Also absolutely not clear why you're trying to create a pseudo async method for this. Remove it. This is something that needs to be synchronous, you have to avoid any form of re-entrancy. -- You *could* perform a complex search (not the case here) asynchronously, but you need to disable/enable a bunch of stuff while this happens. In your case, it's just a source of problems.

Comment: Maybe [Search in for items in CheckedListBox C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66083396/14171304)

Comment: Would you be able to clarify what this code is for and why? It may give more clarity to others to provide an answer that is accurate to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with both JohnG and Jimi and will use their comments to provide suggested improvements to your posted code. The first change is to eliminate the Timer. Consider an update method that is triggered by any change of the textbox or the filter checkboxes. Subscribe to those events by overriding `OnHandleCreated` in the main form:

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    if (!DesignMode)
    {
        // Add notifications for text and checkbox changes.
        textbox_username.TextChanged += searchUpdater;
        CB_botsFilter.CheckedChanged += searchUpdater;
        CB_peopleFilter.CheckedChanged += searchUpdater;

        // Populate the checked list with all users.
        foreach (var user in usernames)
        {
            checkedlistbox_users.Items.Add(user);
        }
    }
}
```

...where the `searchUpdater` handler method is defined as:

```
private void searchUpdater(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var found = new List<string>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox_username.Text))
    {
        if (CB_botsFilter.Checked && CB_peopleFilter.Checked)
        {
            found.AddRange(usernames.FindAll(x =>
                x.StartsWith(textbox_username.Text)));
        }
        else
        {
            if (CB_botsFilter.Checked)
            {
                found.AddRange(usernames.FindAll(x =>
                    x.StartsWith(textbox_username.Text) &&
                    x.Contains("bot", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
            }
            if (CB_peopleFilter.Checked)
            {
                found.AddRange(usernames.FindAll(x =>
                    x.StartsWith(textbox_username.Text) &&
                    !x.Contains("bot", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
            }
        }
    }
    DisplayFound(found.ToHashSet());
}
```

Your code appears to be trying to place check marks next to the users found by the filter. That outcome could be achieved by iterating the Items collection and setting the check `true` if `foundValues` contains the string and otherwise false. I have added a multiline textbox to display the filter result for diagnostic purposes.

```
private void DisplayFound(HashSet<string> foundValues)
{
    textBoxTmp.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, foundValues);
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedlistbox_users.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        checkedlistbox_users.SetItemChecked(
            i, 
            foundValues.Contains(checkedlistbox_users.Items[i]));
    }
}
```

This might not be the *exact* outcome you want, but taking into account the feedback given by the three of us it should give you enough ideas to solve your problem especially with the `OutOfRangeException`.

This graphic shows what the result of various searches would be.

[image]