# In C# .Net 3.5 Windows Form application, implement type-ahead search of ListBox for typed text and set selected index to first match

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I maintain a C# .Net 3.5 Visual Studio Windows Form legacy desktop application. In the application, a ListBox’s DataSource utilizes a bounded DataTable filled from a database SQL query.

I want to create a “type-ahead” search for my ListBox. I use a TextBox’s entered text to implement the “type-ahead” search of the ListBox Items and get the index of the first Item that matches the entered text and call method SetSelected to that index. The text to match may be anywhere in the ListBox Items not just at the beginning of the Item.

The ListBox may have thousands of entries therefore, I am trying to use LINQ or some other way to directly find a matching Item instead of iterating through each ListBox item checking if the TextBox.Text occurs anywhere in the ListBox Item. Even when I tried the iteration technique, I did not get the expected results.

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text) == false)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i <= lbItems.Items.Count - 1; i++)
         {
             if (lbItems.Items[i].ToString().ToUpper().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToUpper()))
            {
               lbItems.SetSelected(i, true);

               break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The below works but only matches from the start of the ListBox Item.

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Ensure we have a string to search.   

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
    {
        // Find the item in the list and store the index to the item.

        int index = lbItems.FindString(txtSearch.Text);

        // Determine if a valid index is returned. Select the item if it is valid.

        if (index != -1)
            lbItems.SetSelected(index, true);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("The search string did not match any items in the ListBox");
    }
}
```

Can I use LINQ or some other way to directly find the index of a ListBox Item that contains a string without iterating through the ListBox Items?

Any other hints as to how to implement a “type-ahead” Item search selection in a ListBox?

Comment: Is the data all in the list box (i.e., it's not a virtual list or anything like that)?  LINQ doesn't really buy you anything other than simpler programming - it's still going to scan all the data.  You might consider building some sort of index for the list (keeping a dictionary of starting letter and index into the list, for example).  It's likely not going to be easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer did not work for me as needed. The ListBox just scrolled for too long and no item became selected.

I went the indexing route in an attempt to get a working solution.

The ListBox DataSource binds to a DataTable filled by DataAdapter from a simple SQL database query of a company id and company name from a company table.

```
OleDbDataAdapter daList = new OleDbDataAdapter();

/*
SQL query (sSQL) of DataAdapter.
SELECT COMP_ID, COMP_ID||' - '||COMP_NAME COMP_NAME FROM COMP ORDER BY COMP_ID
*/
daList.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(sSQL, clsMain.conBLASR);

DataTable dtList = new DataTable();
daList.Fill(dtList);

if (dtList.Rows.Count == 0)
{
  lbItems.Enabled = false;
  lbItems.Items.Add("No data found");
  cmdOK.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
  //Bind the ListBox to the DataTable.
  lbItems.DataSource = dtList;          
  lbItems.DisplayMember = sDisplayName; // sDisplayName = "COMP_NAME"
  bItems.ValueMember = sKeyName;        // sKeyName = "COMP_ID"
  lbItems.SelectedValue = sKeyValue;    // sKeyValue = sCompId
}
```

The following code works for finding the text in the TextBox within the ListBox and selecting the matching item.

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lbItems.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            DataRowView drvLBItem = (DataRowView)lbItems.Items[i];

            String lbString = drvLBItem["COMP_NAME"].ToString().ToUpper();

            if (lbString.Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToUpper()))
            {
                lbItems.SetSelected(i, true);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to not iterate through all the items and maybe use LINQ or some other technique to directly access the ListBox item that contains the TextBox's text and make it the selected item.

Comment: ahh. I thought selecting all the matches in a multi-selection enabled `ListBox`. Anyways, what if more that one item **contains** the search text? Not practical search approach. Note, for a list with thousands of items as you mentioned, LINQ won't be any faster.

Comment: For the LINQ, you can do something like: `var dr = dt.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>(lbItems.DisplayMember).IndexOf(txtSearch.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);` then `if (dr != null) lbItems.SelectedValue = dr.Field<int>(lbItems.ValueMember);`

Comment: The ListBox is "SelectionMode" "One" and for my situation, the user will normally be typing a company name to select in the ListBox. The "txtSearch_TextChanged" event works okay for that scenario. After typing the second letter a high probability of selecting the right company exists and increases with inputting more letters I will definitely need sufficient user testing to see if the method meets their requirements. This method has significant benefits over scrolling through thousands of items looking for the company.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested the alternative solution (the second code block in my answer). I think the filter approach is more efficient so you can get something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66083396/14171304). However, you know better about your requirements. Good luck.

Comment: I tried using the filter approach, but the build fails with a syntax error on the ternary statement, "var filter =".txtSearch.Text.Trim().Length > 0? $"{lbItems.DisplayMember} LIKE '%{txtSearch.Text}%'" : null; Maybe a Visual Studio or C# compiler version issue.

Comment: It looks like string interpolation came out in C# Version 6.0.

Comment: Replace `$"{lbItems.DisplayMember} LIKE '%{txtSearch.Text}%'"` with `string.Concat(lbItems.DisplayMember, " LIKE '%", txtSearch.Text, "%'")`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! The filter method works quite well. I will present the users with both techniques and see which they prefer. I like how the ListBox gets paired down to only matched items. Thanks again!

Comment: Improve the first option (Selection) by starting the search from the currently selected index not from `0`, so every `Enter` hit or button click selects the next match if any until no more, then start again from `0`. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned:

> *a ListBox’s DataSource utilizes a bounded DataTable filled from a database SQL query.*

Accordingly, `lbItems.Items[i].ToString()` does not return what you think, the item's text, it returns `System.Data.DataRowView` which is the type of the item when the `DataSource` is a `DataTable`. You need to call the [`GetItemText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method to get the [`DisplayMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-listcontrol-displaymember).

```cs
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txt = txtSearch.Text.Trim();

    for (int i = 0; i < lbItems.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        bool b = false;

        if (txt.Length > 0)
        {
            var itemText = lbItems.GetItemText(lbItems.Items[i]);
            b = itemText.IndexOf(txt, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
        }
                
        lbItems.SetSelected(i, b);
    }
}
```

Alternatively and instead of selecting the matched items, you can *filter*
the view by setting the [`DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=net-6.0) property. You just need to write:

```cs
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filter = txtSearch.Text.Trim().Length > 0
        ? $"{lbItems.DisplayMember} LIKE '%{txtSearch.Text}%'"
        : null;

    (lbItems.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the indexing route, here's a solution that lets you skip a lot of entries and jump based on the first letter typed.  After the first letter, it's a sequential scan.  You could refine it if you liked.

First, add a list to hold the words (that list will be bound to the Listbox as a data source) and a dictionary to hold the index:

```
private List<string> _wordsList = new List<string>();
private Dictionary<string, int> _wordsIndex = new Dictionary<string, int>();
private int _lastIndexFound = 0;
```

I scrapped a handful of web pages (including this one and some news stuff), copying and pasting to Notepad (to convert the clipboard to text only) and added the file to the project with "Copy Always".  At startup, I read that in, throw away everything that isn't a word, and sort it.  The result is a list with a couple of thousand unique words, in case-independent sort order:

```
var fileContents = File.ReadAllText("TextFile1.txt");
var words = fileContents.Split(' ', '\t', '\r', '\n');
const string wordPattern = @"^[a-zA-Z].*";
var wordRegex = new Regex(wordPattern);
foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (wordRegex.IsMatch(word))
    {
        _wordsList.Add(word);
    }
}
_wordsList = _wordsList.OrderBy(word => word).Distinct().ToList();
```

Then I build the index:

```
var curLetter = "a";
var lastLetter = "z";
var curIndex = 0;
_wordsIndex.Add(curLetter, curIndex);
foreach(var word in _wordsList)
{
    ++curIndex;
    if (!word[0].ToString().Equals(curLetter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        var nextCurLetterChar = (char)(curLetter[0] + 1);
        curLetter = nextCurLetterChar.ToString();
        if (string.Compare(curLetter, lastLetter, true) <=0)
        {
            _wordsIndex.Add(curLetter, curIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here's my TextEntered event code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var enteredText = textBox1.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(enteredText))
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        _lastIndexFound = 0;
        return;
    }
    var firstLetter = (char)enteredText[0];
    if (_wordsIndex.TryGetValue(firstLetter.ToString(), out var firstLetterIndex))
    {
        for(var i = firstLetterIndex; i < _wordsList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_wordsList[i].StartsWith(enteredText, true, null))
            {
                _lastIndexFound = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = _lastIndexFound;
    }
}
```

It's pretty quick and dirty code and it's had only light testing.  But, it seems to work.